# HELP!!! List Comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

Раздел: алгоритмические задачи на Яндекс Контест.
Помогите разобраться с list comprehension. При обычном цикле все работает как нужно. Но есть требование от ревьювера, чтобы цикл for был заменен на list comprehension.

Вот реализация до ревью:

```
users = []
for _ in range(n):
    login, count_task, penaltie = input().split()
    users.append(User(login, int(count_task), int(penaltie)))
```

Моя попытка реализации после ревью:

```
users = [User(*input().split()) for _ in range(n)]
```

Проблема в том, что моя реализация не работает как нужно и не проходит все тесты. Например, Входной файл:

```
5
alla 4 100
gena 6 1000
gosha 2 90
rita 2 90
timofey 4 80
```

Вывод программы:

```
gena
alla
timofey
gosha
rita
```

Правильный ответ:

```
gena
timofey
alla
gosha
rita
```

Код:

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class User:
    login: str
    count_task: int
    penaltie: int

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if self.count_task == other.count_task:
            if self.penaltie == other.penaltie:
                return self.login > other.login
            return self.penaltie > other.penaltie
        return self.count_task < other.count_task

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return other > self

    def __str__(self):
        return self.login


def quicksort(arr, left, right):
    if left >= right:
        return -1
    pivot = arr[(left + right) // 2]
    lt, rt = left, right
    while lt <= rt:
        while arr[lt] < pivot:
            lt += 1
        while arr[rt] > pivot:
            rt -= 1
        if lt <= rt:
            arr[lt], arr[rt] = arr[rt], arr[lt]
            lt += 1
            rt -= 1
    quicksort(arr, left, rt)
    quicksort(arr, lt, right)


def main():
    n = int(input())
    users = []
    for _ in range(n):
        login, count_task, penaltie = input().split()
        users.append(User(login, int(count_task), int(penaltie)))
    quicksort(users, 0, n-1)
    print(*users, sep='\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При вашем вызове нет преобразования `str` в `int`.
Можно создать функцию обработки массива:

```
def k(arr):
    return [arr[0], int(arr[1]), int(arr[2])]

def main():
    n = int(input())
    users = [
        User(*k(input().split()))
        for _ in range(n)
    ]
    quicksort(users, 0, n-1)
    print(*users, sep='\n')
```

Можно использовать `lambda`:

```
def main():
    n = int(input())
    users = [
        User(*(lambda arr: [arr[0], int(arr[1]), int(arr[2])]) (input().split()))
        for _ in range(n)
    ]
    quicksort(users, 0, n-1)
    print(*users, sep='\n')
```

Comment: Спасибо, ваше решение оказалось верным

Answer (score 1):

у вас на входе `User` в первом примере второй и третий параметр - целые числа (`int`)

а во втором примере - строки (`split()` же строки возвращает)

может такую конструкцию попробовать:

```
[int(v) if i else v for i, v in enumerate(text.split())]
```

Comment: к сожалению не подошло решение, но спасибо за просвещение

Answer (score 1):

можно еще такую штуку провернуть:

```
users = [User(l,int(c),int(p)) for l,c,p in [input().split() for _ in range(n)]]
```